# An error occurred while receiving data: '24(The program issued a command but the command length is incorrect.)'

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

When I try to setup ServiceBroker communication between 2 SQL Server instances, based on different Azure IaaS servers, `sys.transmission_queue.transmission_status` mentions the following error I am not able to decypher:

```
An error occurred while receiving data: '24(The program issued a command but the command length is incorrect.)'.
```

Can somebody shed light on this unsual error message, in a ServiceBroker perspective?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You'll want to look in the SQL Server errorlog for other errors and the windows logs, looks like it might be something not inside of SQL.

Comment: Thanks @SeanGallardy for the reply. Actually, I found no related "error-tagged" entry in Windows Events logs :/

Comment: And in the SQL Log files?
And what is the output from ssbdiagnose?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/ssbdiagnose/ssbdiagnose-utility-service-broker?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Acutally @PeterKruis, the ssbdiagnose tool does not help that much in my case, because it is not a basic one :/

I use different service accounts on both computers, the initiator being itself a group Managed Service Account for which I don't basically know the password (that's the aim ^^). So I can't provide login/password for FROM SERVICE part and -E switch takes my own Windows authentication credential, that is not a valid test :/

Comment: Do you have the possibility to add an Profiler or Extended event on both sides and look for the Audit Broker Login class. Do you get an error on those items?
Or perhaps someone does know that passwords and can run the ssbdiagnose tool for you?

Comment: Thanks @PeterKruis. Actually I am administrator, so I have access to passwords. But gMSA accounts has the particularity of managing passwords rotation so that even admins are not aware of. 

Regarding Audit Broker login class, 
* on initiator side, the error message is the same `An error occurred while receiving data: '24(The program issued a command but the command length is incorrect.)'`
* on target side, the error message is `Connection handshake failed. The login 'DOMAIN\gMSA-INIT-ACCOUNT$' does not have CONNECT permission on the endpoint. State 84`
...

Comment: ... but which _endpoint_ is concerned in the error mesasge on target side? The mentioned account is not intended to be authenticated on target aide. So I tried `GRANT CONNECT ON ENDPOINT::InitiatorEndpoint TO [DOMAIN\gMSA-INIT-ACCOUNT$]` with no better luck :(

Comment: Does it mean that a gMSA account is not candidate to run service broker feature, unless it is authenticatable on both initiator and target side, which is really not the aim of gMSA? :/

Comment: Perhaps you can add those users in a group and give the group rights on the endpoints?

Perhaps is somehting usefull in this document (maybe you've already read it)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb839483.aspx